# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Tags: python, pandas, function, data-science, naivebayes

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import nltk
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
**this is the library**

df = pd.read_csv('spam.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

**the dataframe**

    def get_feature(text):
        if len(text)==2:
            return {'ham':text[-3]}
        elif len(text)>=1:
            return {'spam':text[-3]}
        else:
            return {'ham':'', 'spam':''}

**get future**

    def get_feature_text(text):
        if len(text)==2:
            return {'spam':text[-2], 'ham':text[-1]} 
    
        else:
            return {'spam':DataFrame.rename(text[-2])[0], 'ham':DataFrame.rename(text[-1])[0]}

**get future of text**

    def get_data(df, get_feature=get_feature):
        featrues = []
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            text = row['v1']; type = row['v2']
            if isinstance(text, str):
                if ' ' in text:
                    text = text.replace(' ', '')
                if '(' not in text:
                    featrues.append((get_feature(text), type.strip('() ')))
                else:
                    text = text.partition('(')[0]
                    featrues.append((get_feature(text), type.strip('() ')))
        return featrues

**get data all**

    def get_train_test(featrues, ratio=0.9):
        N = len(featrues)
        T = int(N * ratio)
        train = featrues[:T]
        test = featrues[T:]
        return train, test

**train and test**

    def text_classifier(df, f=get_feature):
        data = get_data(df, f)
        train, test = get_train_test(data)
        classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train)
        acc = nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test)
        return classifier, acc

**text classifier**
   

 def show_type_of_text(text, texts=False, show_acc=False):
        f = get_feature_text if texts else get_feature
        classifier, acc = text_classifier(df, f)
        if show_acc: 
            print("The accuracy of prediction is: ", acc)
        clf = classifier.classify(f(text))
        print(f'{text}: {clf}')
        classifier.show_most_informative_features(10)

**show type of text**

    def give_type(type1='spam', type2='ham'):
        data = get_data(df, get_feature)
        classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(data)
        following = classifier.prob_classify({'ham':type2, 'spam':type1})
        x = following.generate()
        print(f'{type2}: {type1}{x}')

**give type**

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('-wait a minute-')
        show_type_of_text("spam")
        print((text_classifier(accuracy_score)))

**i expecting to print the score
```

from this script I want to score the accuracy of the code that I made but here the problem is itterows then what should I do? I've read the documentation about accuracy_score but still the same result doesn't want to come out**

**
from this script I want to score the accuracy of the code that I made but here the problem is itterows then what should I do? I've read the documentation about accuracy_score but still the same result doesn't want to come out**

Comment: Hello on SO! Your question likely will not be answered in such a shape. Try to format the code properly and first of all try to distil the problem - remove unnecessary parts of code, leave only problematic ones.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).